# Determine whether cursor is above some element in Raphael.js

Tags: if-statement, hover, raphael

How can you tell if your cursor is over a certain element in Raphael.js?

```
if(mouse_is_over){
   //do this 
}
else{   
   //do this 
}
```

Ideally, I would like to test if the mouse if over a circle I named 'c'.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if this helps, but you can write a mouse hover function, as in whenever the element gains focus set mouse_is_over to true for that element, when focus is lost make mouse_is_over = false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly recommend using Raphael's [Element.data](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.data) method to associate your private, circle-specific data with each item, and then acting on or against that data in a hover handler (manually detecting intersection with getElementByPoint may be expensive in a mouseover handler).  You can store anything with `data`:

```
var circle = paper.circle( ... );
circle.data( 'name', "My name is Jonas." ); // store a string!
circle.data( 'dataset', { ... } );          // store an object literal!
circle.data( 'click_handler', function()
    {
        console.log("Store a handler function!" );
    } );
```

At this point, the game becomes very easy.  Whether you use Raphael's built in hover handling...

```
circle.hover( function()
    {
        console.log("Just moved over '" + this.data("name") + "'" );
    }, function()
    {
        console.log("Just moved out of '" + this.data("name") + "'" );
    } );
```

...or a mouseover event powered, for instance, by jQuery...

```
//  Don't forget to translate page coordinates relative to the paper!
var element = paper.getElementByPoint( x, y );
if ( element && element.data("name") == "c" )
{
    // bah, humbug
}
```

...the logic is the same.  Simply query the application data you've associated with your elements and do your thing.

I happened to already have a terrible little script that animates circles at random locations, and I [retrofitted it](http://voidblossom.com/tests/circleHover.php) to accommodate your scenario.

Comment: To help clarify my question, I'll be generating a dynamic set of circles.  There could be 2, or there could be 5, at random positions.  How could I test to see if I was hovering over a circle, and if I was, which circle it was?

Comment: That is helpful.  I will amend my answer to clarify.

Comment: Lucid, brief, and a useful set of examples.  Great answer.

Comment: in my case I have many many svg paths (raphael objects), and putting a hover handler on each seems a bit heavy. ... ... ...